# last elements of table in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

How can i get the last N elements of a table?
I have used this query but it does not seem to work.

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select top 7 * from dailystats order by daily_ID desc;", null);
```

Comment: use `limit`, `"select * from dailystats order by daily_ID desc LIMIT 7;"`

Comment: Thanks man, can you please make it as an answer so that I check it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For earning the point, I make my comment as an answer as requested by the OP;)

use `limit`, `select * from dailystats order by daily_ID desc LIMIT 7`

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`limit`](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby):

```
select * from dailystats order by daily_ID desc limit 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

Top is for SQL Server You need to use Limit

```
select * from dailystats order by daily_ID desc limit 7;
```

OR to Select just the last row

```
select * from dailystats where daily_ID = (select max(daily_ID) from dailystats);
```

Comment: Neither of those queries returns the top `N` - only the top 1.

Comment: @MattBall, ya my bad, just thought about returning last row, going to edit it now

Answer (score 0):

If you allow me to convert all those answers to more Android-code like:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String tableName = "dailystats";
String orderBy = "daily_ID desc";
String limit = String.valueOf(5);
Cursor cursor = database.query(tableName,
                               null, //all columns
                               null, // no where clause
                               null, // no where arguments
                               null, // no grouping
                               null, // no having
                               orderBy,
                               limit);
```

From then on you use the `cursor` as any other `cursor` in Android. It will hold the top `limit` results with respect to the `orderBy` column in descending order.